# iOS Safari - what event triggers the progress bar to go away?

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile, web

Trying to make a site feel faster to the user on load. What browser event triggers the blue progress bar to 'finish' and go away?

onload?

Comment: Maybe just work on making your site load faster, e.g. reduce scripts and images to minimum size.

Comment: we're doing everything, making it tiny and arranging the load order